# How to implement Auto sliding iCarousel in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, slider, ios8

I have implemented  a basic slider using iCarousel iOS library but i dont know how to make it as a Auto slider instead of manual swipe sliding.

Here is my sample project code Pls help me

[Code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6caVk8MnBVadTg4UTNIV183X3M/view?usp=sharing)

When i searched in google i got this link,but i didnt understand anything

https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel/issues/84

Answer (score 2):

This solved my problem
in ViewDidAppear() i have added following line

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    sliderCount=0;
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0f target:self selector:@selector(runMethod) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void)runMethod
{
    [self.carousel scrollToItemAtIndex:sliderCount animated:YES];
    if(sliderCount== 7)
    {
        sliderCount=0;
    }
    else
    {
        sliderCount++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `ViewDidLoad method` in your `Viewcontroller`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //configure carousel
    carousel.type=iCarouselTypeCylinder;
    carousel.autoscroll=0.4;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the github link, I assume you want to autoscroll to an item upon view.

You have defined the function

```
- (void)scrollToItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index animated:(BOOL)animated
```

However this isn't part of the iCarousel delegate, its already defined as part of the class, therefore you just need to call it. Putting it in viewDidAppear would seem appropriate if you wanted it to auto scroll to a particular index when your view controller was presented to the user. Simply add the method below.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    // The index of 3 was just chosen as an example
    NSInteger chosenIndex = 3;
    [self.carousel scrollToItemAtIndex:chosenIndex animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: is there any way to make it like auto scroll everytime like the one in iOS APP Store sliding

Comment: like something based on a timer

Comment: Sure, if you implemented a timer, and once that fires every second or so, increase the index and call the scrollToItemAtIndex function. You probably want to set the wrapEnabled property on iCarousel to YES, so that the scrolling continuously wraps.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    carousel.type=iCarouselTypeCylinder;
    carousel.autoscroll=0.8;
    [carousel reloadData];
}
```